# Setting model title in MySQL Workbench for Forward Engineering

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, tools

In MySQL Workbench, when viewing a model, you can select `File->Export->Forward Engineer SQL Create Script`.

The first four lines of the generated file are a comment, something like this:

> -- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
>   -- Mon Dec 17 11:21:48 2018
>   -- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
>   -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

How do you change the model title and version?  Is there any way to have an autoincrement on version, especially with semver options autoincrementing the patch number?

I don't see it in any tab of `Model->Model Options`.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box with these controls is under `File->Document Properties`.
There is no way to autoincrement the version number in this dialog.